# How to stop vim from automatically scrolling while typing in insert mode

Tags: vim, windows-7

I have an annoying problem with vim which I have googled to death to no avail. I would like vim to stop scrolling right when I am typing in insert mode. I do not have this problem when I enlarge the vim window, but I would like to keep the window small and compact for my own purposes.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
As requested by merlin2011 here is the contents of my .vimrc file.

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

Comment: @Amadan set wrap succeeds at wrapping the text to the next line when reaching the set text-width, but the screen still scrolls right until it reaches the end of the line when I'm typing.

Comment: That is very weird, since `wrap` has nothing to do with `text-width`, and should wrap line display at window width. There should be no horisontal scrolling with `wrap`.

Comment: What is the smallest Window size you can have before you start seeing this problem?

Comment: @merlin2011 If I make the window smaller than the default window size when vim is opened then I will start to see this problem. Just to clarify though, the problem is that when I type, vim keeps the cursor left most to the window,  thus scrolling the window right. Also, I have a similar problem with vim scrolling vertically which is also annoying. If I could just stop automatic scrolling all together that would be great.

Comment: Can you show the contents, if any, if your vimrc or the system's vimrc?

Comment: Also, if you run vim and show us the output of the `:set` command, that might also reveal the the problem.

Comment: Vim has to either scroll or wrap the text to that the cursor remains visible as you type. I don't fully get your problem, but would changing `'sidescrolloff'` be of any help?!

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem exactly, though I can keep the cursor to the right-most part of the screen and have it scroll a single character at a time as I type. I have done this by setting `sidescrolloff=1` (minimum number of screen columns to keep to the left and to the right of the cursor) and `sidescroll=1` (minimum number of columns to scroll horizontally). I would look playing with those settings. Perhaps try putting them both to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and I think I managed to fix it, but it wasn't a vim issue. Could you try right clicking on your cmd prmpt window, go into properties and make sure this has been checked? When I checked that box vim stopped locking onto my cursor and scrolling sideways when I typed. Let me know if that works.

[image]